# Python to Open html files in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a bunch of purchase orders in .html formats that I need to extract data and put in one simple excel sheet. While I could use beutifulsoup to do it I would rather just use excel's in built converter which already does a much better job. Then just work with excel files directly. Is there a way to use python to open html documents, then save it again in .xlsx. I tried using openpyxl but it does not take html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python to automate an instance of the Excel application, opening each file, and saving as `.xlsx`:

```
import win32com.client
excelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
book = excelApp.Open(path_to_html_file)
book.SaveAs(path_to_html_file + '.xlsx', 51)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tablepyxl](https://github.com/martsberger/tablepyxl) to read the html into excel if the data you want is in tables in the html.